# VBA Excel Copy/Paste Specific Range from multiple worksheet

Tags: excel, runtime-error, copy-paste, vba

I have been looking online for a solution but I keep getting an error no matter what I try.

I have about 20 worksheets and I want to copy the same range for each worksheet and merge them to another worksheet to create a report.

I was able to modify this solution below but it's still not working and I don't know why.

Any help is appreciatd.

```
Sub forReport()

   Dim lRow As Long
   Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim shReport As Worksheet
    Set shReport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ALLProjectForReport")

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case sh.Name
            Case Is <> "ALLProjectForReport"
                lRow = shReport.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
               Set copyRange = sh.Range("A:B,D:D,F:F,J:K,L:L,BK:BK,GA:GB,GF:GF")

               copyRange.Copy Destination:=shReport.Range("A" & lRow)                    

        End Select
    Next
    Set shReport = Nothing
    Set sh = Nothing
End Sub
```

But every time I get an error run-time '1004' highlighting this line

```
 copyRange.Copy Destination:=shReport.Range("A" & lRow)
```

Any help?

Comment: You can't copy a whole column and paste it halfway down a sheet - you run out of cells. Think you need to reconsider `copyRange`.

Comment: when setting `lRow` you need to use `lRow = shReport.Cells(shReport.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`. otherwise it will take the `Rows.Count` from the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: @ShaiRado You are right for the lRow. Thank you i have changed it :)

Comment: @SJR Ok, that make senses... Is there a way I can copy a range("A2:lRow") for each worksheet then paste it from the ("A" & lRow) of that specific sheet I want?

Comment: Yes though presumably the lRow will be different in each case . @A.S.H's solution below may do the job for you.

Comment: @SJR YES IT DID!!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this quick-fix:

```
Set copyRange = Intersect(sh.UsedRange, sh.Range("A:B,D:D,F:F,J:K,L:L,BK:BK,GA:GB,GF:GF"))
```

Comment: Yes it worked!!!! Thank you so much!! I'm gonna read about this method. Thank you so much... How do i marked a question as answered? I gave it "thumbs up" but it's still showing zero ...

Comment: @DrD4rk You're welcome, glad to help :). The acceptance is the gray checkmark below the triangles :)

Comment: yaayyy. Thanks again. You just made my day!